# How to determine angle of incidence, resulting position, and resulting velocity for a point with position and velocity appearing within a rectangle?

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, physics, angles

I have a rectangle positioned on a 2D Cartesian coordinate system, and its minimum x and minimum y are represented as a coordinate pair (`xrect`, `yrect`). I also know the rectangle's width `w` and height `h`.

I also have an x,y-coordinate pair for a point that intersects the rectangle (`x1`, `y1`). This point may appear anywhere inside the rectangle or touching one of its sides. I am also given the point's velocity vector components `vx` and `vy`, and I know that the point has been traveling in a straight line at constant speed.

How can I determine:

- which side of the rectangle the point contacted first?
- what the (x,y)-coordinate was at the point of contact?
- what the angle of incidence would have been had the point been deflected at the coordinate of first contact?
- what the resulting vector components would be for the point's velocity?